# Window not opening in a new tab

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer, menu

I have a menu link that is to pop-open a page in a new tab. I am using IE11 but have many users still on IE9. 
This is the code that I am using in the web.sitemap:

```
<siteMapNode url="~/Forms_Admin/Maintenance/AdminUtility.aspx?window=new"  title="LookUp Utility" roles="XXXX"></siteMapNode>
```

If I open in FireFox or Chrome this will open in a new tab, but in IE it just opens in the same window.

How do I get this to open in a new tab?

Thanks

Comment: I don't see anything indicating that something *should* open in a new tab/window/etc.  What actually instructs the browser to do this?

Comment: Yes, the code did not save but... I have in the sitemap siteMapNode url="~/Forms_Admin/Maintenance/AdminUtility.aspx?window=new"  title="LookUp Utility" roles="OCTPUser"></siteMapNode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just include target=_blank in the declaration.

```
<siteMapNode url="~/Forms_Admin/Maintenance/AdminUtility.aspx?window=new" target="_blank" title="LookUp Utility" roles="XXXX"></siteMapNode>
```

Comment: I had that in there but it still doesn't open in a new tab

Comment: I had to add to the page code in the menuItemDataBound event                'AdminUtility.aspx
        If (e.Item.NavigateUrl.Contains("window=new")) Then
            e.Item.Target = "_blank"
        End If

Answer (score 0):

`target="_blank"` on the source page was lost when the page rendered for me. I had to do it in the code behind like so:

```
private void Menu1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MenuItem adminUtilityItem = new MenuItem("LookUp Utility");
    adminUtilityItem.NavigateUrl = "~/Forms_Admin/Maintenance/AdminUtility.aspx?window=new";
    adminUtilityItem.Target = "_blank";
    Menu1.Items.Add(adminUtilityItem);
}
```